# Error during statement execution in broadleaf while running tomcat ant task

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

i had setup broadleaf with mysql db and when i run ant task for tomcat the some database tables are created but some error also there due to that 404 error while accessing localhost:8080/

error are in image file--

[click on link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e01Qv.png)

Comment: Post your full stack trace.

Comment: how can i insert full code i stuck with code is not formatted as code so i provided with image

Comment: please give me steps how can provide full code

Comment: Copy the exception that you are getting, edit your post and add that exception log using code tag. Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask